# JAWS doesn't read alert in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, alert, jaws-screen-reader

If I submit a form by pressing enter inside the form from an input, the page reloads without reading the error message. But if I am on the submit button and either press it or click it, the page reloads reading the error message at the top. Why would it not read the error message if submitting from within the form?

Also, when submitting within the form, the focus goes to the submit button when page reloads, whereas the other way, it just focus's normally at the top ( not focusing on the error message itself, just the top of the page ).

Comment: Here, I can see you have 2 issues. one with your own web page and other with JAWS. Can you provide a sample code to produce the issue. I will try to check for the focus issue on page reload. It can be possible that JAWS only read if it has focus on alert.

Comment: I ended up adding a tabindex to the div and then focusing on it if it was visible. I assumed that if a div had an alert tag that is visible it would read it. Looks like you have to focus on the tag for it to be read.

Comment: @ Keith, In your previous comment. You had shared the solution for your issue. If the issue is solved than I suggest you to post that solution as an answer for this thread and mark it as an answer may help other community member in future.